# Long distance wired communication between 2 raspberry pi

Tags: communication

I need to send video feed from one raspberry Pi to another raspberry Pi for 10 meter . Can I use Ethernet cable ? what do i need to do?

Comment: REFERENCE: [Wikipedia on Fast Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet) for everything you ever wanted to know  :)

Comment: `Can I use Ethernet cable` - yes ... `what do i need to do` - use ethernet cable

Answer (score 1):

The maximum distance for Ethernet [10/100T] is 100 meters so 10 meters is no problem.
Look into using vlc to stream video from a USB webcam or a Pi camera.
https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html